# Google cached version of my website is not working due to CORS issue

Tags: seo, google-cache, cors

Do I need to whitelist `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com`? What is the impact on SEO if the cached version does not load properly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please give the cached version of the url and the correct url, using **example.com**

Comment: I don’t think this question is confusing at all, and how would the URL help?

Answer (score 1):

When Googlebot indexes your site, it does so with the origin set correctly. This means CORS requests work fine for Google as they would do for a normal visitor. Therefore there is no SEO impact.

However, it may still be good for user experience if the cached version worked for users. If you know Google’s rehosting of your site as a cached version provides no value to users without CORS and you don’t want to allow CORS from the cached version, prevent Google from serving the cache by setting the `noarchive` [robots directive](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag).